# Como faço para um array através de uma de função?

Tags: c#, array, funções, unity3d

Estou escrevendo um código no Unity é preciso passar vários valores através de uma função, resolvi utilizar o *array* na declaração da função, no entanto quando eu tento recuperar os valores do *array* todos eles são definidos como 0, o código esta da seguinte forma

```
public class ArrayTest : MonoBehaviour{

private int[] number;

void Start(){
    number = new int[] { 2, 3, 5 };
    Numbers(number);
}

void Numbers(int[] numb) { 
    numb = new int[3];

    Debug.Log("Este é o primeiro valor: " + numb[0]); 
    Debug.Log("Este é o segundo valor: " + numb[1]);
    Debug.Log("Este é o terceiro valor: " + numb[2]);
  }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O que está fazendo não tem o menor sentido. Você recebe um parâmetro e a primeira coisa que faz com ele é jogar fora seu valor e criar outro valor. Ou faz algo com o parâmetro ou faz algo com a variável local que deseja.

Só retire a linha que reinicializa o parâmetro `numb` (péssimo nome) dentro de `Numbers()` que funcionará.

O código parece ter outros problemas, ainda que funcione, mas não posso falar nada porque não sei o que está tentando fazer.